# How come get(field_name__c) works with the values returned from CustomMetadataType__mdt.getAll().values()?

Tags: apex, custom-metadata

I have something similar to following:

```
for(CustomMetadataType__mdt config : CustomMetadataType__mdt.getAll().values()){
    //we usually use this to access the field values
    System.debug(config.Field_Name__c);
    //but this seems to work as well!
    System.debug(config.get('Field_Name__c'));
}
```

Is this a known thing and how come? get() is used both with map (with key) and list (with index). Interested to know about this behavior. Thanks!

Comment: okay, my bad! just found out that it is also used as one of the SObject methods to get the value based on field name: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that get() is also one of the methods from SObject class to get the value based on field name! Apologies for not knowing!
Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get

Comment: You can also use the get method with a field token, as in `config.get(CustomMetadataType__mdt.Field_Name__c)`;

Comment: awesome! yea just saw it in the same ref documentation